# Avoid repeating regex substitution

Tags: regex, vim

I have lines of code (making up a Ruby hash) with the form of:

```
"some text with spaces" => "some other text",
```

I wrote the following vim style regex pattern to achieve my goal, which is to replace any spaces in the string to the left of the `=>` with `+`:

```
:%s/\(.*\".*\)\ (.*\"\ =>.*\,)/\1+\2
```

Expected output:

```
"some+text+with+spaces" => "some other text",
```

Unfortunately, this only replaces the space nearest to the `=>`. Is there another pattern that will replace all the spaces in one run?

Comment: What are you expecting as output? (Also that substitution doesn't do anything for me)

Comment: Reiterating, this is in Vim. The desired effect is to replace all spaces to the left of `=>` in all lines like the above, giving:
`"some+text+with+spaces" => "some other text:,`

Comment: Can you put the expected output in the question? (That was all I was really asking)

Comment: Sorry about that, @FDinoff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really far from perfect, but it does nearly the job:

```
:%s/\s\ze[^"]*"\s*=>\s*".*"/+/g
```

But it doesn't handle escape quotes, so the following line won't be replaced correctly:

```
"some \"big text\" with many spaces" => "some other text",
```

Comment: That's awesome! I don't have any escaped quotes, so it works. I wish I had used this instead of repeating my query until all the spaces that I wanted to change were changed.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than write a large complex regex a couple of smaller ones would easier

```
:%s/".\{-}"/\=substitute(submatch(0), ' ', '+', 'g')
```

For instance this would capture the everything in quotes (escaped quotes break it) and then replace all spaces inside that matched string with pluses.

If you want it to work with strings escaped quotes in the string you just need to replace `".\{-}"` with a slightly more complex regex `"\(\\.\|[^\"]\)*"`

```
:%s/"\(\\.\|[^\"]\)*"/\=substitute(submatch(0), ' ', '+', 'g')
```

If you want to restrict the lines that this substitute runs on use a global command.

```
:g/=>/s/"\(\\.\|[^\"]\)*"/\=substitute(submatch(0), ' ', '+', 'g')
```

So this will only run on lines with `=>`.

Relevant help topic `:h sub-replace-expression`