# Match all words within double quotes

Tags: regex, vim

I'd like to have a regular expression to match all words within double quotes.

Consider the line:

```
the quick "brown fox" jumps
```

The words `brown` and `fox` should be matched, but not `the`, `quick`, or `jumps`.

The following is my first attempt:

```
".*\zs\w\+\ze.*"
```

Unfortunately, the greed of `.*` causes the regex to consume more than I want, and just the `x` in `fox` is matched. By using `\{-}` instead of `*` (vim's non-greedy equivalent) we get the modified regex:

```
".\{-}\zs\w\+\ze.*"
```

But this only matches the first word in the quotes (`brown`), and not all of them as I'd like.

Can what I'm trying to do be accomplished with a regular expression?

Comment: What are you trying to do as a result of the match?

Comment: The actual problem I ran into was matching all non-underscore-prefixed classes in a jQuery selector. i.e. `.one` and `.three` in `.find(".one ._two .three").click()`. The same problem caused by `.*` and `\{-}` arises.

Comment: Are you trying to delete them? Are you trying to replace them with something? I would probably recommend something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25539112/1890567

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. I want them all highlighted so that I can examine them and jump to them with `n`.
The codebase I'm working with follows a convention that non-underscore classes should only be used for styling, and underscore-prefixed classes should only be used for manipulation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the positive lookbehind `\@<=` and positive lookahead `\@=` you can get the following:

```
\("\(\w\+ \)*\)\@<=\w\+\(.*"\)\@=
```

So you demand that zero-width match of `\("\(\w\+ \)*\)`, meaning a quote character followed by 0 or more words followed by space `\(\w\+ \)` needs to match before the pattern. After the pattern, you can have a sequence of any characters `.*` followed by quote, but this needs to match as well.

See `:h /\@<=` and `:h /\@=` for more examples. `\zs` can often be used instead of `\@<=` but in this case it only matches the last word.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I'm wondering, why does \zs only match the last word in this case, when `\@<=` doesn't?

Comment: It might be said in documentation in some sense (`:h \zs`): *Can be used multiple times, the last one encountered in a matching branch is used.* A simpler example where the difference between the two shows would be `\(a*\)\zsa` vs. `\(a*\)\@<=a` when matching a sequence `aaaa`.